# Element by element exponential multiplication in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to execute a custom function within MatLab, such that `x` which is a vector is actually the exponent of a constant `e`.  I've tried placing the `dot` in numerous places, but it keeps throwing an error which is telling me to use the `.` before the `^`, which is not what I want to do on this occasion.  `Y` needs to return a vector and not a constant.

```
x = [0:0.1:1];

    function y = hyperT(x)

    e = exp(1); 
    y = ((e^x*2)-1)/((e^x*2)+1);

    end
```

I've taken the `.` out for the purpose of this thread.

Comment: Would this work - `y = ((e.^x.*2)-1)./(e.^(x.*2)+1)`?

Comment: It just returns a constant `0.5770`

Comment: @user1574598: If I use x = [0:0.1:1]; e = exp(1); y = ((e.^x.*2)-1)./(e.^(x.*2)+1); I get a vector, not a constant. Please explain your issue.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I needed so many `.`'s.  I missed the one before the division sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a vector, you can use ([MATLAB power operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)):

```
y = ((e.^x*2) - 1) ./ (e.^(x*2) + 1);
```

The `.` operator basically means "element-wise". For example, if you are multiplying two vectors, `x = [x1, x2, x3]` and `y = [y1, y2, y3]`, then using the `.*` operator multiplies each element by the corresponding element in the other vector, while using the `*` operator without the `.` performs an inner product ([matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)):

```
x.*y = [x1y1, x2y2, x3y3]
x*y = error (inner matrix dimensions must agree)
x'*y = [x1y1, x2y1, x3y1;
        x2y1, x2y2, x3y2;
        x1y3, x2y3, x3y3]
x*y' = x1y1 + x2y2 + x3y3
```

Note that the `'` in the above transposes the vector.

Some operators automatically broadcast because their use is un-ambiguous. Thus you do not need the `.` with the `+` and `-` operators. Oddly enough, the division operator does not auto-broadcast, so you need to use `./` there ([MATLAB rdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html)). I am not sure what it is doing when you omit the `.`, but it seems to be well defined and consistent at least.

In general, you can perform any operation (even one that you define) element-wise between two vectors, or between a constant and a vector, by using `bsxfun` ([MATLAB bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)). For example, to perform the power operation that you are asking about, you could do:

```
bsxfun(@power, e, x)
```

or

```
bsxfun(@power, e, x*2)
```

This is actually a super-efficient way to do a lot of neat things, but in your case the functionality is already built in with `.^`.

**Edit:** Added some links

Comment: Thanks, I understand that multiplying two vectors would result in a dot or cross product (only if the dimensions agree).  Its just a bit confusing that I needed a `.` before the division sign.  Nonetheless, this seems to produce the graph I needed `y = ((e.^x.*2)-1)./((e.^x.*2)+1);`

Comment: @user1574598 That `.` before `/` denotes that you are interested in performing element-wise division and not the matrix-division. Not sure what's the confusion there.

Comment: I've only just caught your edit, yes the `bsxfun` seems a much more efficient way to do this.  This is nothing serious anyway, as I'm just trying to create a graph from a hyperbolic tangent equation from a book I'm studying.

Comment: @Divakar how is matrix division defined in MATLAB? The documentation is unclear to me. But yes, `./` is clearly what we want here.

Comment: @Divaker - Sorry, no confusion now as I understand fully.  Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @Engineero `/` would be matrix division and `./` is element-wise division.

Answer (score 1):

you may use:
`expm(x)` which is matrix exponential.